# C++: template function to retrieve value from an union

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a template to get value from a collection that can hold different data types. for ex a variant structure. But i get a warning when the compiler generates code for assignments with other types. for ex

```
struct Variant
{
    enum Type
    {
        _bool,
        _int
    };
    Type type;

    union VAL
    {
        bool bVal;
        int nVal;
    }val;
};

template <typename ValType>
void GetValue(Variant v, ValType val)
{
    if(v.type == Variant::_bool)
    {
        val = v.val.bVal;
    }
    else if(v.type == Variant::_int)
    {
        val = v.val.nVal; // C4800
    }
}

Variant v;
v.type = Variant::_bool;
v.val.bVal = true;

bool bVal(false);
GetValue(v, bVal);
```

Warning:

```
warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

Can someone suggest on how can the template be re written to get value the right way ?

Comment: Why won't you show us what the warning says?

Comment: Every branch of `GetValue` has to compile for every `ValType`, e.g. the second branch has to compile also for `ValType` being `bool`. This produces an assignment from an `int` to a `bool` - even if this branch should never (intentionally) be executed for `ValType == bool`. You'll need to dispatch to distinct functions to get around this.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I don't get a warning on MacOX clang-600.0.57

Comment: I am using msvc 2012 compiler.

Comment: @dyp , Yes i think thats the only way to resolve this but can I do this just with templates.

Comment: Side-remark: Why are you not using a variant from one of the many libraries that provide one? E.g. [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: actually this is just an example. the code iam working with has a internal structure that very much behaves like the variant structure. thanks for the reference i'll look into the boost::variant and see if its helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template for `GetValue` for `ValType === bool`, `val` is of type bool.
Thus the line `val = v.val.nVal;` results in the warning.

In order to provide special code for special types, there is template specialization.

You can specialize the function template like

```
template<class T>
void GetValue(Variant v, T & val);

template<>
void GetValue<int>(Variant v, int & val)
{
  if (v.type == Variant::_int)
    val = v.val.nVal;
}
template <>
void GetValue<bool>(Variant v, bool & val)
{
  if (v.type == Variant::_bool)
    val = v.val.bVal;
}
```

Note: `v.type` does not determine which one will be called, the argument does.

Answer (score 1):

First, as [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314823/c-template-function-to-retrieve-value-from-an-union#comment48725336_30314823) already suggested in the comments, I would recommend looking at [`Boost.Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html).

That said, the issue you're running into is that regardless of what type you're storing internally, every branch always has to be compiled the way you wrote it - and some of those branches might not make any sense (what if you added an array or some other POD type?) The way Boost solves this issue is by requiring the user to pass in a functor, and you call that functor with the right type:

```
template <typename F>
void visit(Variant v, F visitor)
{
    if(v.type == Variant::_bool) {
        visitor(v.val.bVal);
    }
    else if(v.type == Variant::_int) {
        visitor(v.val.nVal);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

So then, you just write a visitor:

```
struct get_bool {
    void operator()(bool b) {
        bVal = b;
    }

    template <typename OTHER>
    void operator()(OTHER ) { }

    bool& bVal;
};
```

And use it:

```
bool bVal(false);
visit(v, get_bool{bVal});
```

Comment: The visitor can as well be written as a template, of course. And the else-if chain is typically a `switch` (so that a static analyser can catch missing enumerators).